# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugAssets'. > unable to create new native thread

Tags: java, android, cordova

**Cordova** project was created and successfully build the gradle, but when we run the app on device or emulator then getting the below error

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugAssets'.
>   unable to create new native thread

How to resolve this . Please help us

Comment: You forgot to add your question